# SQL pivot to transpose data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to use pivot (or maybe some other solution) to just transpose data. I don't have to worry about aggregating any information, I literally just want to transpose rows and columns.

I have a table where each record stores answers to a series of questions. The structure looks like this where all questions are yes/no bits:

```
(pk)ID, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5....
```

I want to take a query like

```
select ID, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5               
from mytable          
where myconditions
```

and transpose it so that I get

```
ID 1 2 3 4
q1 1 1 0 1
q2 1 0 0 1
q3 0 0 1 1
q4 1 1 1 1
q5 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Why? Isn't this much easier done on application level?

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to create a report in SSRS for this data, but don't see a way to do what I want with tables or matrices.

Comment: Then you're blind obviously...Just use a table and drag&drop what you get from your query to whatever axis you need it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but a table in Bids/Data Tools has two rows, one is for headers and one is for data. It automatically adds rows for each record in the dataset. I don't see anyway to choose an axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
From
(
  select id, col, value
  from mytable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  min(value)  
 for ID in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) piv
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8894/15)

**Op:**

```
COL 1   2   3   4
q1  1   1   0   1
q2  1   0   0   1
q3  0   0   1   1
q4  1   1   1   1
q5  0   0   1   0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I never realized that the [1],[2],[3] in the pivot were static text. I always thought they were supposed to be placeholders for column names or something and that was what was throwing me off.

Comment: I have one or two text fields and unpivot doesn't like that different datatypes are being used. Any ideas how to amend if one of the fields being pivoted is varchar instead of bit?

Comment: I ended up sticking my data in a temp table that had everything converted to nvarchar and running the unpivot/pivot on that.